# History, first use, of Wizards?

Tags: wizard

I was just now criticizing Wizards in a [comment](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/83773/should-wizard-be-used-for-edit-and-modify-why-or-why-not).

In fact, what was the first Wizard, and when?

Indeed, can one fairly and definitively state: *"Microsoft invented Wizards"* ...?

Comment: I found this SO question that talks about the history of the wizards - not so surprisingly, starting with Microsoft http://stackoverflow.com/questions/896344/why-are-wizard-dialogs-called-wizards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well Roger's answer sums it up pretty nicely but here is another reference I found from **PC Mag** (that agrees that 91/92 is when this type of wizard arrives from Microsoft).

[**PC Mag -** Oct 26, 1993](https://books.google.com/books?id=nhSywJ4rn6UC&pg=PA81&lpg=PA81&dq=publisher+2.0+wizard&source=bl&ots=kz7-QQkF7_&sig=X4COL6h8SULkONlg0J2lGOWkJQk&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCcQ6AEwAWoVChMInISmipnMxwIVx8uACh1TdASC#v=onepage&q&f=false)

> Microsoft sparked the trend with a series of Wizards that came with Microsoft Publisher 1.0, Microsoft Excel for Windows 4.0, and Microsoft Access. Eschewing the step-by-step tools approach found in most software, Wizards take a more task-oriented path to helping you get your work done.

[Access](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Access) and [Excel 4.0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Excel) were 1992.

[Publisher 2.0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Publisher) was 1991.

Comment: fantastic information, I thank you.  What a great site this is!

Comment: Is it a plain fact that **"Microsoft invented Wizards"**?

Comment: I don't know for sure but unless the [MacUser Magazine](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/65777/123175) referenced in Roger's answer was referring to something earlier than Microsoft then it appears, yes, in the context of a step-by-step software guide, they were the first.

Comment: I'll second it coming from MS:  I have this hazy recollection of using an early version of Powerpoint with a Wizard sometime in the early 90s.

Answer (score 4):

It's not really a UX question, but...

In the context you imply (i.e. a software assistant) then 1991/1992 was the first mention or introduction of wizards as you can read in the answers to the question [Origin of the term “wizard” in computing](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/65728/origin-of-the-term-wizard-in-computing) on the English stack exchange site.

Comment: Had no idea it was so long ago, good one.